# Was the method of transmitting an image in "Danny Dunn and the Voice from Space" inspired by scientific literature or vice versa?

Tags: aliens, communication

In my answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/272470/three-teens-build-an-electronic-telescope-that-peers-into-another-galaxy/272478#272478) where I suggested *Danny Dunn and the Voice from Space*, I mentioned the image that the protagonists receive from space via a radio telescope, which was decoded in part because they recognized that the signal consists of 559 "bits", the product of two primes, 13 and 43.

[image: Image of the transmitted message]

Someone commented on the similarity to the [Arecibo message](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arecibo_message), which used a similar trick of sending out a message that made an image by using dimensions of two primes, and how this was likely an homage, but as per my reply, much to my surprise, the novel was published in 1967, while the Arecibo message wasn't sent until 1974!

I know that Carl Sagan was consulted for the Arecibo message. I assume that the idea of using two primes to increase the likelihood that an intelligent civilization would try interpreting it as a grid image existed somewhere in the scientific literature, which Raymond Abrashkin and Jay Williams, as well as the composers of the Arecibo message, drew upon, but I'm not finding any evidence of that yet. Or did Raymond Abrashkin and Jay Williams come up with it, and then it was used for the Arecibo message?

Comment: While it is safe to assume the Franke Drake role. A bit of digging turned up the prime raster grid art idea was originated by his colleague Bernard M. Oliver shortly after a 1961 conference. Source   Communication with Extraterrestrial Intelligence 
by LD CALLIMAHOS (1965 ?) https://www.nsa.gov/portals/75/documents/news-features/declassified-documents/cryptologic-spectrum/communications_extraterrestrial_intelligence.pdf or original article 
photocopy  https://media.defense.gov/2021/Jul/13/2002761372/-1/-1/0/COMMUNICATION_WITH_ET.PDF

Comment: At first glance it would appear the message says "A crab monster alien from a binary star system is taking a rocket invasion fleet to a 9 planet solar system".  But I'm no Danny Dunn.

Comment: @lucasbachmann OOPS! I posted my (redundant) answer without reading the comments. Sorry about that!

Comment: @lucasbachmann - Yes, but how do you explain the one off centre dot? Is it just a dead pixel?

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica: there's only one planet in that system, as opposed to nine in the top.

Comment: @Nick Matteo - Ah yes, of course! But, how come the 9-element system is symmetrical though? Couldn't the single planet have been placed in the middle and thus preserved symmetry?

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica: Maybe the planet orbits the star represented on the left of the binary system?

Comment: That is the case. The two stars depicted are identified in the book as [61 Cygni A and B,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/61_Cygni)  with a mutual orbital period on the order of 680 years, and both are K-Class, so any world warm enough for liquid water would orbit only one of the stars, fairly close. (Also, Sir Edward, one of the characters in the book believes that the planet orbits one of them.)

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica with only 559 pixels - that does certainly limit accuracy.  The Arecibo message message has our solar system all in a line with Earth offset to single it out.  Though an alien may wonder why it's orbit was off plane!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think it's likely that the book was inspired by the preliminary thoughts that [Frank Drake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Drake) had expressed before actually sending his message.  Evidence: Drake is mentioned by the characters in the book itself, and credited by the authors for his help, as mentioned in this [discussion](https://www.abc.net.au/radionational/programs/ockhamsrazor/astronomy--astronomers-in-books/3536648):

> Danny Dunn in 'Danny Dunn and the Voice from Space' visits a radio
> telescope in England that closely resembles the one at Jodrell Bank.
> His experiences have a certain authenticity because the author
> acknowledges assistance from Frank Drake, a respected American
> astronomer closely involved with the SETI project, the Search for
> Extra-Terrestrial Intelligence.

Comment: That's good enough for me. :)